# At/on/in name of a road/street/avenue

Tags: grammar, prepositions

I want to talk about an evening spent walking up and down an avenue.
Which one is correct?

> Evening on Champs-Élysées

,

> Evening at Champs-Élysées

, or

> Evening in Champs-Élysées

?

Does it matter if it is a street, a road, or an avenue?

Comment: We usually say _the_ Champs-Elysees.

Comment: @mdewey is it for all streets or there’s something special about Chemps-Élysées?

Comment: No it's not for all streets. Many towns in England have a road called _High Street_, but people often refer to it as _the High Street_; but most streets don't take _the_ at all. In the city of Oxford, _High Street_ and _Broad Street_ are generally referred to as _The High_ and _The Broad_ (without "Street"), but that's peculiar to Oxford.

Comment: I daresay it's following the French practice of shortening _l'Avenue **des** Champs-Élysées_ (the avenue **of the** Elysian Fields) to _**les** Champs-Élysées_ in casual speech or writing. It is named for **the** Elysian Fields, the final resting place of the souls of the heroic and the virtuous in Greek mythology. When I go to Nice, I often pass along l'Avenue Jean Médecin, and I would say 'on [Avenue] Jean Médecin'.

Comment: @ColinFine - I have been accustomed to calling a road 'the XXX road' if it leads to the place called XXX, e.g. there is a road near me which is the Gloucester road, which leads to the city of that name, which is about 50 miles away. Part of it in my locality is named 'Gloucester Road' and is referred to without an article. Lately I have become irritated by a mainly London practice of calling any prominent road 'the XXX Road' even when it doesn't lead to the place, e.g. 'the Portobello Road'.

Answer (score 1):

This is one of those difficult questions where it depends on which variety of English.

As far as I know, nowhere do people say **at** with a Street. But the choice of *in* or *on* is not straightforward.

I believe that in AmE, *on* is much more common with street names; but in BrE, both are used, and I think *in* is more common.

If I search the GloWbE corpus for "in/on the street", I get about equal numbers for UK sources (3388 'on':3415 'in') but more than 2:1 for US sites (3727 'on' : 1585 'in').

Trying to do the same comparison with a namd streete is harder, because I can't find many street names that are common on both sides, but *in/on Market Street* gives 34 'on':2 'in' for US, against 11 'on' : 12 'in' for UK.

On the other hand, *in/on the Champs Elysees* does give a different picture: 19 'on' : 1 'in' for UK (and only 2 US in total, both 'on'), so it appears that *on the Champs Elysees* is more common everywhere.

Partly it depends what you're locating there. *I live* may be followed by *on* or *in*; *I was walking* is far more likely to be *in* in BrE - but not apparently in AmE, or Indian E.